# URL rewriting not working in Express 4.14.1

Tags: javascript, express

I've found in quite a few SO posts that in order to rewrite a URL in Express 4 I would do something like the following:

```
router.use('/one/:someId', (req, res, next) => {
    req.url = `/two/${req.params.someId}`;
    next();
});

router.get('/one/:someId', (req, res) => {
    res.send("reached /one/:someId");
});

router.get('/two/:someId', (req, res) => {
    res.send("reached /two/:someId");
});
```

But when I try this, not only does the URL does not change to my expected "/two/*some integer*" and stays being "/one/*some integer*" but it gets to the 404 - Not Found page I have set up in my app file.

This routes are in a router file and I have also tried setting the URL to:

```
req.url = `/routerPath/two/${req.params.someId}`;
```

but the result is exactly the same.

So what could I be missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to distinguish two kinds of redirects:

- Internal redirects work on the server, without the client noticing. They are a convenience for your server programming and never necessary - you could always introduce a helper method that gets called by all endpoints.
- HTTP redirects advise the client (e.g. a web browser) to go to a different URL. Since you expect the URL to change, that's the one you want.

Simply call [`res.redirect`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect), making sure to encode special characters:

```
router.get('/one/:someId', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect(`/two/${encodeURIComponent(req.params.someId)}`);
});

router.get('/two/:someId', (req, res) => {
    res.render("reached /two/:someId");
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is one among many exercises to learn about Express' features and capabilities. The thing is that if I use redirect I loose some context that I am trying to send to the second end point via parameters in the req object. Also, from your answer, it would seem that the whole idea of middleware is not really necessary since by using helper methods you make calling them explicit instead of relying in carefully placing each method in the correct order. Would you agree or am I missing something?

Comment: If you want to keep parameters, you have four options: Either encode them in the URL (i.e. redirect to  `/two/$someid?param1=foo&param2=bar`), or store them on the client for further processing (e.g. with cookies), or store them on the server for further processing (requires session management, i.e. cookies as well) or (POST only) redirect with HTTP code 307 so that the client resends the entire POST body. [continued...]

Comment: ... Yes, middleware is always equivalent to a helper function that you call in every affected handler. The advantage of middleware is that you don't have to explicitly call it in every handler. That's important if you have lots of handlers your middleware applies to. In this case, it's only two handlers that share the code, so it's not that big of a deal. Whether you use a middleware that redirects internally or a helper function, for the client the URL will remain `/one/foobar`.